# Python UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position

Tags: python

```
def handle_client(self, client_socket, address):
    size = 1024
    while True:
        try:
            data = client_socket.recv(size)
            if 'q^' in data.decode():    
                print('Received request for exit from: ' + str(address[0]) + ':' + str(address[1]))
                break

            else: 
                body = data.decode()

        except socket.error:
            client_socket.close()
            return False

    client_socket.sendall('Received request for exit. Deleted from server threads'.encode())
    client_socket.sendall('q^'.encode())
    client_socket.close()
```

The error happens on `if 'q^' in data.decode():`

The data comes from an iOS client

```
connection.send(content: "SOME_STRING".data(using: .utf8)!, completion: NWConnection.SendCompletion.contentProcessed({ error in
                print(error)
            }))
```

There are similar questions on SO, but non of the solutions solved the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your client side you encoded the characters as bytes using `utf-8`.

On your server side you decode the bytes to characters without specifying an encoding.  Based on the exception message in your question title, your environment tried to use `ascii` to decode the bytes.  However, the bytes are not valid for ASCII.  You want to explicitly specify the encoding:

```
data.decode("utf-8")
```

You should also specify the encoding when you encode your message that you send from your python server.

I would also recommend performing the `decode()` only once, rather than twice, for each chunk that you receive.

```
def handle_client(self, client_socket, address):
    size = 1024
    while True:
        try:
            raw_data = client_socket.recv(size)
            data = raw_data.decode('utf-8')
            if 'q^' in data:    
                print('Received request for exit from: ' + str(address[0]) + ':' + str(address[1]))
                break

            else: 
                body = data

        except socket.error:
            client_socket.close()
            return False

    client_socket.sendall('Received request for exit. Deleted from server threads'.encode('utf-8'))
    client_socket.sendall('q^'.encode('utf-8'))
    client_socket.close()
```